# Jquery/CSS sequential element animation with callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I am writing a script that will animate a set of jQuery Elements, but I'm running into some issues. Here are my requirements:

- Sequential animations
- Callback functionality after all animations are complete. Callback can be defined globally
- Animation works on floated elements with
- Entire solution can be js/jquery/css or a combination

Here's what I've gotten so far: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/cqAws/

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">Im a box</div>
<div class="block">me too</div>
<div class="block">and me!</div>
<div class="block">am I?</div>
<div class="block">yes.</div>
<div class="block">Im a box</div>
<div class="block">me too</div>
<div class="block">and me!</div>
<div class="block">am I?</div>
<div class="block">yes.</div>
<div class="block">Im a box</div>
<div class="block">me too</div>
<div class="block">and me!</div>
<div class="block">am I?</div>
<div class="block">yes.</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.block{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.hiddenForAnimation{ opacity:0; margin-top:-20px; }
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $('.block').addClass('hiddenForAnimation').each(function(i){
        var delay = i * 200,
            animationSpeed = 800;
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity: '1', marginTop: '0px'
        }, animationSpeed, function(){ if(typeof afterPageAnimation === 'function' && i === $(this).length){ setTimeout(afterPageAnimation, delay + animationSpeed);} $(this).removeClass('hiddenForAnimation').attr('style',''); });
    });
});

function afterPageAnimation(){ alert('animation is done!'); }
```

My issues:

- Is there a better way to refactor this JS script to be sequential? Using `delay()` is effective, but not elegant.
- The callback is not being executed directly after the animations
- When the last element in a row finishes animating, the first element in the next row starts at the far right, then jumps to the left (I suspect `margin-top` has something to do with this.)

Thanks!

Comment: Well, .hiddenForAnimation{ opacity:0; margin-top:0px; } will get rid of the jumping. You can also remove the line that sets margin top from js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works

http://jsfiddle.net/cqAws/12/

Remember: In positioning animations, use `position:relative` or `position:absolute` and play with `top, left, right, bottom` instead of margins.
It's better

EDIT: made it a little better.

Comment: Awesome! I initially tried using `top`, but had no luck. That's because I didn't `position:relative`. D'oh! The only point this answer doesn't go over is whether or not there is a better way to refactor?

Comment: why use another counter variable when you have the index argument in the loop? just check `if(i == $('.block').length-1)`

Answer (score 1):

**new**

```
$(function(){
    j=0;
    $('.block').each(function(i){
        var interv = +(i*800);
        var animationSpeed = 800;

        $(this).toggleClass('hiddenForAnimation')
               .delay(interv)
               .animate({opacity: '1', marginTop: '0'},animationSpeed,function(){
                   j++;
                   $(this).delay(+(interv+animationSpeed))
                          .toggleClass('hiddenForAnimation')
                          .attr('style','');
                          if(j>=+($('.block').length)) afterPageAnimation();

               });
    });
});

function afterPageAnimation(){ alert('cool'); }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tUN9c/2/)

Comment: Did you change the markup at all? I'm getting a different result. All elements are animating in at once. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/tUN9c/

Comment: `afterPageAnimation()` is not firing =X

Answer (score 0):

For future viewers:

I've solved this by creating a small Jquery plugin found here: https://github.com/fillswitch/Jquery-Sequential-Animations

Hope this helps some other users in the future!